# AES with GUI not working

Tags: encryption, javafx, cryptography, aes

I am developing a AES-128 bit symmetric key encryptor in JavaFX. Here is my doubt: The below attached class **encrypt method is called** when a person **clicks on encrypt button**. But when someone tries to decrypt the file using the given method **it doesn't actually decrypt**. It gives a **file that's still encrypted**.

**The same thing when I performed for a console based program it worked flawlessly.**

GUI class (Excerpt of the project which don't work !)

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESEncryption {

private final File toBeUsed;
private final String password;

public AESEncryption(String passkey, File given){
    this.password = passkey;
    this.toBeUsed = given;
}

public void encrypt(boolean toBeLocal){
    Service<Void> encryption = new Service<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {

            return new Task<Void>(){

                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    if(toBeLocal) this.startEncryption();
                    this.success();
                    return null;

                }

                private void success() {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            EncryptionSuccessController controller = (EncryptionSuccessController)new OfflineWindow("/fxml/encryption_success.fxml", "Success").getLoader().getController();
                            controller.setPath(toBeUsed.getAbsolutePath()+".enc");
                        }

                    });
                }

                private void startEncryption() throws Exception{
                     SecureRandom randomizer = new SecureRandom();
                     byte[] salt = new byte[16];
                     randomizer.nextBytes(salt);

                     byte key[] = (password+salt).getBytes("UTF-8");  
                     MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                     key = sha.digest(key);
                     key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);

                     SecretKeySpec pass = new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");  
                     Cipher encrypt =  Cipher.getInstance("AES");  
                     encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pass);

                     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(toBeUsed.getAbsolutePath() +".enc");
                     try(FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream(toBeUsed.getAbsolutePath())){
                        try(CipherOutputStream cout=new CipherOutputStream(fos, encrypt)){
                            copy(fis,cout);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                     }
                }

                private void copy(InputStream is,OutputStream os) throws Exception{
                     byte buf[] = new byte[4096];
                     int read = 0;
                     while((read = is.read(buf)) != -1) os.write(buf,0,read); 
                }
            };

        };
    };
    encryption.start(); 
}

public void decrypt(boolean isLocallyEncrypted){
    Service<Void> decryption = new Service<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {

            return new Task<Void>(){

                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {

                    if(isLocallyEncrypted) this.startDecryption();
                    this.message();
                    return null;

                }

                private void message() {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            DecryptionCompleteController controller = (DecryptionCompleteController)new OfflineWindow("/fxml/decryption_over.fxml", "Completed").getLoader().getController();
                            controller.setPath(toBeUsed.getAbsolutePath());
                        }

                    });
                }

                private void startDecryption() throws Exception{
                    SecureRandom randomizer = new SecureRandom();
                    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
                    randomizer.nextBytes(salt);
                    byte key[] = (password+salt).getBytes("UTF-8");  
                    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                    key = sha.digest(key);
                    key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); 

                    SecretKeySpec pass = new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");  
                    Cipher decrypt =  Cipher.getInstance("AES");  
                    decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pass);
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(toBeUsed.getAbsolutePath());
                    try(CipherInputStream cin=new CipherInputStream(fis, decrypt)){  
                       try(FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(toBeUsed.getAbsolutePath().substring(0,toBeUsed.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(".")))){
                          copy(cin,fos);
                       }
                    }
                }

                private void copy(InputStream is,OutputStream os) throws Exception{
                     byte buf[] = new byte[4096];
                     int read = 0;
                     while((read = is.read(buf)) != -1) os.write(buf,0,read); 
                }
            };

        };

    };
    decryption.start();
  }

}
```

Console based code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


public class AES {
private String algo;
 private String path;
 private String password;
 public AES(String algo,String path, String password) {
     this.algo = algo; //setting algo
     this.path = path;//setting file path
     this.password = password;
    }

    public void encrypt() throws Exception{
     SecureRandom padding = new SecureRandom();
     byte[] salt = new byte[16];
     padding.nextBytes(salt);
         //generating key
     byte k[] = (password+salt).getBytes("UTF-8");  
     MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
     k = sha.digest(k);
     k = Arrays.copyOf(k, 16);  
     for(int i=0;i<k.length;i++) System.out.print(k[i]);
         SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k,algo);  
         //creating and initialising cipher and cipher streams
         Cipher encrypt =  Cipher.getInstance(algo);  
         encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
         //opening streams
         FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(path+".enc");
         try(FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream(path)){
            try(CipherOutputStream cout=new CipherOutputStream(fos, encrypt)){
                copy(fis,cout);
            }
         }
     }

     public void decrypt() throws Exception{
     SecureRandom padding = new SecureRandom();
     byte[] salt = new byte[16];
     padding.nextBytes(salt);
         //generating same key
      byte k[] = (password+salt).getBytes("UTF-8");  
     MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
     k = sha.digest(k);
     k = Arrays.copyOf(k, 16); 
      for(int i=0;i<k.length;i++) System.out.print(k[i]);
         SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k,algo);  
         //creating and initialising cipher and cipher streams
         Cipher decrypt =  Cipher.getInstance(algo);  
         decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
         //opening streams
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
         try(CipherInputStream cin=new CipherInputStream(fis, decrypt)){  
            try(FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf(".")))){
               copy(cin,fos);
           }
         }
      }

  private void copy(InputStream is,OutputStream os) throws Exception{
     byte buf[] = new byte[4096];  //4K buffer set
     int read = 0;
     while((read = is.read(buf)) != -1)  //reading
        os.write(buf,0,read);  //writing
  }

}
```

As always expecting a best answer from Stack Overflow's intelligent community.

Comment: What happens when you encrypt with the GUI, and decrypt with the console application?

Comment: I am decrypting it with GUI only but GUI decrypt is not working. That's an another project for checking my code which is working fine.

Comment: I mean, if you encrypt with the GUI, take that output, and decrypt in the console, does it work (ie, the encryption portion of the GUI app is working correctly)?

Comment: Can you inspect the decrypt buffer before it gets written to the file?  Is the wrong data perhaps being written to the file, or is decryption not happening at all?

Comment: I tried encryting with console and decrypting with console. It worked fine.

Comment: Please read my question again..

Comment: I read the buffer and I found that it's not decrypting it!

Comment: Is it not decrypting, or is it decrypting incorrectly (ie, does the 'decrypted' buffer differ from the encrypted data)?

Comment: I found the issue with the key! (not to be confused with cryptographic key)...see my code you can find a byte[] key which is generated using SHA-1. Then it's transformed into the SecretKeySpec pass. That byte[] key is different for both encrypt and decrypt method in GUI based app. It's where I smell foul. And regarding your previous comment @roelofs...it's true encrypted and buffer data are different.

Comment: Sooo, your initial question has been answered?

Comment: But I don't why it's different? I can't figure it out !

Comment: I've given an answer below - does that help?

Comment: Some general tips: look into other modes than ECB (the default for Cipher most of the time) and check out some PBKDF2 samples). Voted roelofs answer up of course, generating a different key each time and trying to decrypt with it is not going to end well...

Comment: -1 this will never work in a console application either.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the salt value in your GUI application is different between encrypt and decrypt.  I'm not sure why it would be the same in your console application, but to get the same key using the method you're using, the salt should also be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your salt is random for both encryption and decryption; this will never work as the key is different each time (which you should have noted).

You cannot just concatenate a byte array to a string. Implicitly a `toString()` method is called, which just shows some information about the reference.

```
public class AES_GUI {
    private String algo;
    private String path;
    private String password;

    public AES_GUI(String algo, String path, String password) {
        this.algo = algo; // setting algo
        this.path = path;// setting file path
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void encrypt() throws Exception {
        SecureRandom padding = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        padding.nextBytes(salt);
        // generating key
        byte k[] = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        sha.update(salt);
        k = sha.digest(k);
        k = Arrays.copyOf(k, 16);
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++)
            System.out.print(k[i]);
        System.out.println();

        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k, algo);
        // creating and initialising cipher and cipher streams
        Cipher encrypt = Cipher.getInstance(algo);
        encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        // opening streams
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + ".enc");
        fos.write(salt);
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path)) {
            try (CipherOutputStream cout = new CipherOutputStream(fos, encrypt)) {
                copy(fis, cout);
            }
        }
    }

    public void decrypt() throws Exception {
        BufferedInputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path + ".enc"), 16);

        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        int read = fis.read(salt);
        if (read != 16) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        // generating same key
        byte k[] = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        sha.update(salt);
        k = sha.digest(k);
        k = Arrays.copyOf(k, 16);
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++)
            System.out.print(k[i]);
        System.out.println();
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k, algo);
        // creating and initialising cipher and cipher streams
        Cipher decrypt = Cipher.getInstance(algo);
        decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        // opening streams
        try (CipherInputStream cin = new CipherInputStream(fis, decrypt)) {
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + ".dec")) {
                copy(cin, fos);
            }
        }
    }

    private void copy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Exception {
        byte buf[] = new byte[4096]; // 4K buffer set
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = is.read(buf)) != -1)
            // reading
            os.write(buf, 0, read); // writing
    }
}
```

**Note that this code is not secure**. You should try and use PBKDF2 for key derivation from a password and use a different mode of operation than ECB (which is the default for the SUN provider of Oracle. Also note that I slightly altered the code for testing purposes.